# Vertical Line within Navigation Menu

Tags: asp.net, syncfusion

i have tried to set a vertical Line (Separator) between my Items in a MenuItem (Navigation-Menu).
i used a Div-Tag but bacome an Error: that  is not allowed within a Syncfusion.Web.UI.WebControls.Tools.MenuControl.Panel. can you tell me how can i fix this Problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Border style for “.DefRoot_ItemCSS” class should be customized to get the separators between menu items. Changes to this class will be reflected in all the menu items. If you want to apply this only for particular item then this can be set by using id of that element such as #MainContent_Menu1_I2{ border-right: 1px solid;}.

Thanks,

Varalakshmi